# convert linq code to dotnet 2.0

Tags: asp.net

```
    string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("images");
    string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");

    using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(pdfpath + "\\NLI_Filled_out.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(imagepath + "\\sign2.gif", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(pdfpath + "\\NLI_Filled_output.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);

        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

        var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(3);

        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);

        image.ScalePercent(24f);

        image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 130);

        pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);

        stamper.Close();
    }
```

I have the above code in 3.5 using linq..i want to convert it into dotnet 2.0...can anyone pls help...

Comment: Do you just have a 'using System.Linq;' at the top? If so just remove it and see if you get any errors meaning you do have Linq code in this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no LINQ there.  Your problem is that (if you're targeting C# 2.0 for whatever reason) the `var` keyword isn't supported in versions earlier than 3.5.  Just change the `var` instances to the explicit appropriate class (PdfReader, PdfStamper, and whatever the return type of GetOverContent is).